# Unable to retrieve OrderbyChild() data from firebase database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have database structure is like this screenshot:

[image]

I had used `orderByChild()` to retrieve data from firebase Database using my Input as `RegId`, But I'm getting the values as `NULL`.

Please tell me how to retrieve data using `RegId` as Input from user.

```
return admin.database().ref('Table/'+RegId).orderByChild('RegId').once("value").then((snapshot) => {
    var name = snapshot.child("FirstName").val();
    agent.add(`The student name is ` + name);
    var email = snapshot.child("EmailId").val();
    agent.add(`The student Mail is ` + email);
    var Regno = snapshot.child("RegId").val();
    agent.add(`The student Register no is ` + Regno);
})
```

I got output as:

The student name is null

The student Mail is null

The student Register no is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

This means that your code will need to handle this list by looping over `snapshot.forEach()` in the callback:

```
return admin.database().ref('Table/'+RegId).orderByChild('RegId').once("value").then((snapshot) => {
  snapshot.forEach((user) => {
    var name = user.child("FirstName").val();
    agent.add(`The student name is ` + name);
    var email = user.child("EmailId").val();
    agent.add(`The student Mail is ` + email);
    var Regno = user.child("RegId").val();
    agent.add(`The student Register no is ` + Regno);
  });
})
```

Comment: Following code is working But agent.add() function is not working i.e not getting output value to user.`var ref = admin.database().ref().child("Table/");
var query = ref.orderByChild("RegId").equalTo(RegId.toString());`
`query.once("value", function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(child) {`
  `console.log(child.key);
  console.log("FirstName: " + child.val().FirstName);
  console.log("Mobile: " + child.val().MobileNumber);
  console.log("Email: " + child.val().EmailId);`
`var name = snapshot.child("FirstName").val();
  agent.add(`The student name is ` + name);`
  
    });

Comment: agent.add() is not working,But console.log() is giving values in Firebase Database logs.But i need agent.add() to show output values to user

Comment: The only change I made in my answer is to add a `snapshot.forEach(...)` loop, which is needed for the reasons I explained. There might be other problems with your code too, but this is definitely one thing you'll need to change.